# React-navigation not a component type?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

very basic example. I'm trying to render my StackNavigator within my App component and I'm getting "Expected a component class, got [object object]". I've seen it working on few different tutorials but I'm trying to patch few things in one project and while doing it that very basic issue is not letting me proceed. I will appreciate any help, thanks!

My current code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StackNavigator } from "react-navigation";

import { View, Text } from 'react-native';

class MainScreen extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: "Welcome"
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Welcome to React Navigation</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const mainNav = StackNavigator({
  // Login: { screen: LoginScreen },
  Main: { screen: MainScreen }
});



class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <mainNav />
    );
  }
}


export default App;
```

Comment: don't you need to extend from `React.Component` instead of `Component`?

Comment: Sorry I just didn't paste the first few lines as they seemed obvious. Updated the example!
Thanks to destructuring of the react by doing { Component } I can use it without the dot notation to answer you question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to rename `mainNav` to `MainNav` because JSX requires components to be capitalized.

Comment: Of course! I will put that on my tiredness. Thanks a lot!

Comment: just beat me to it